# Opened image in picturebox is not editable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

I am writing program similar to MS Paint. I am trying to open a .jpg file using OpenFileDirectory. Code is below :

```
ofd.Reset();
ofd.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif|PNG Image|*.png";
ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\\Users\\Icek\\Desktop";
ofd.Title = "Open";
ofd.Multiselect = false;

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   var.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
}
```

Image is loading properly but I cannot draw on it anymore. Can anybody tell me why it happens?

Comment: For that you need to write code!

Comment: Using Image.FromFile() puts a lock on the file.  So if "editing" actually means "trying to save it back" then no, that won't work.  Don't make us guess at what it really means.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a graphic reference from picture box

How to: Draw Text on a control

```
private void DrawString()
{
    System.Drawing.Graphics pic = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    string drawString = "Sample Text";
    System.Drawing.Font drawFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
        "Arial", 16);
    System.Drawing.SolidBrush drawBrush = new
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
    float x = 150.0f;
    float y = 50.0f;
    pic.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, x, y);
    drawFont.Dispose();
    drawBrush.Dispose();
    pic.Dispose();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawString();
}
```

finally if you get Graphics context then can DrawLine, Curve, Image ...

See [System.Drawing.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info ...